# Why is there a filter in the LQP queue?

Tags: bug, review-queues, low-quality-posts, filtering

I just saw there's a <kbd>filter</kbd> button next to the Low Quality Posts name and it looks like I am able to filter posts by questions and answers:

[image]

Hasn't it been some time since questions were kicked out of LQP, though?